# Как увеличить память диска на VPS сервере под Ubuntu 18, за счет домашнего компьютера под Windows 7 c закрытым портом 80 но открытым 443?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vps, openvpn, portforwarding

у меня есть арендованный VPS сервер Ubuntu 18 с диском на 10 гб. Этого пространства мне не хватает для хранения видео-файлов. Покупать более дорогой тариф мне будет не выгодно, по этому появилась идея расширить дисковое пространство VPS сервера за счет моего домашнего компьютера под Windows 7 c диском 1 ТБ.
Вот только есть одна большая проблема. По умолчанию у меня все порты закрыты (в том числе и порт 80), однако мне удалось договорится с провайдером, и он открыл мне два порта 443 и 27015.
Через роутер я их уже прокинул, и они действительно прокинуты и работают хорошо!

Моей основной задачей является, чтобы дополнительное дисковое пространство работало как чать основного диска VPS сервера (**ТО ЕСТЬ ОТКРЫВАЛОСЬ ПО HTTPS**, и без 3-х минутных ожиданий на открытие каталога или файла).

Забыл упомянуть что я не использую подключение http. Все http запросы переводятся в https. (так что по идее 80 порт то и не нужен наверное) По этому:

Пока я пришел к выводу, что мне подойдет 2 варианта:

1. Получить вилдкарт https сертификат (ну чтобы на все поддомены был) и подключить свой локальный комп поддоменом dopdisk.mysite.ru
   2)Какими-то костылями, открытием VPN тунеля и тд монтировать диск компа в дисковое пространство VPS сервера.

Вот подскажите, люди добрые:
Возможно ли вообще реализовать то что я хочу при закрытом 80 порте любым из этих 2-х вариантов? Может есть вариант лучше?

А также посоветуйте и поправьте если в чем-то ошибся. И если предложите пошаговые действия (как сделать), буду очень благодарен! Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: добавьте своей машине какое-то имя по dns, что бы она была доступна с внешнего мира. А на своем сайте публикуйте просто ссылки  правильные. И ничего не нужно "подключать". Это нормальная практика в современном мире, когда файлы с видео хранятся на других физически машинах

Comment: Я могу добавить имя но раз порт 80 закрыт, браузер пользователя не сможет отправить мне запрос, по этому надо как-то открыть https, но не могу решить проблему с получением https сертификата, так как порт 80 не открыт. А для потверждения владения сервером для сертификации нужен открытый порт 80 как я понимаю.

Comment: Если я буду просто использовать http вместо https, то при встраивании видео-файлов в страницы сайта который открываются через https, браузер пишет ошибку миксед-контент, и запрещает просмотр "незащищенных файлов".

Comment: на lets encrypt - да. Но у Вас же есть ещё один сервер!

Comment: Кажется я глуповат в этом вопросе. Подскажите подробнее, как наличие vps сервера поможет мне?

Comment: на впс сервере можно получить сертификат wildcard. а потом просто скопировать его на свой локальный комп.

Comment: Не обязательно с сертификатом. Вы можете открывать порт на веб-сервере принудительно указывая порт, например: _http://dopdisk.mysite.ru:443 или _http://dopdisk.mysite.ru:27015

Comment: Но чтобы не светить IP своей домашней машины все это лучше делать за reverse-proxy (HAproxy, nginx), Тогда и с сылками можно будет не мучаться, а сделать например чтобы ссылки mysite.ru/download/ отправлялись с домашнего компа.

Comment: можно. Просто траффика будет чуточку больше ганятся через сервер, а так все ок